# How to group all the first characters of a string in a list of string , all second character of a string and so on in a list of string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

a=["cypatlyrm","aolsemone","nueeleuap"]

o/p needed is : *canyoupleasetellmeyournamep*

I have tried

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a)):
        res+=a[j][i]
```

it gives o/p : *canyouple*

how to get full output ?

Comment: See what `list(zip(*a))` returns. This can be converted to the desired output more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest` with fill value as empty string`''` and `itertools.chain` and the `join` the result to get what you want.

```
from itertools import zip_longest, chain

seq = ["cypatlyrm", "aolsemone", "nueeleuap"]

res = ''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(*seq, fillvalue='')))
print(res)
```

Output

```
canyoupleasetellmeyournamep
```

Using `zip_longest` makes sure that this also works with cases where the element sizes are not equal. If all elements in the list are guaranteed to be the same length then a normal `zip` would also work.

If all the elements have the same length then you can use this approach that does not need libraries that have to be imported.

```
seq = ["cypatlyrm", "aolsemone", "nueeleuap"]
res = ''

for i in range(len(seq[0])):
    for j in seq:
        res += j[i]

print(res)
```

Comment: Thank you sm. But just wanted to know ,Is there a way to do this without importing anything. Any logic that could help ?